# With systemd, should environmental variables ever be declared in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables, profile

It seems to me like with [`environment.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html) now sourcing environmental variables in `~/.config/environment.d/*.conf` that we should no longer have environmental variables declared in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or the like. If for no other reason than because these declarations can be written in a shell-specific syntax.

Is this assumption correct? Is there any reason on a machine with environment.d to put our environmental variables (that aren't shell-specific) in our shell's `rc` file or in `~/.profile`?

Comment: Clearly the syntax is limited. If I wanted to loop over, say `/opt/*/bin` and add those to `$PATH`, I don't see how `environment.d` can manage that.

Comment: Clearly. Do I have to update the question and narrow the scope to environmental variables that are set to literals without the aid of scripting?

Answer (score 5):

The files serve different purposes, which remain complementary:

- `environment.d` defines [variables for systemd user services](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html#Applicability);
- `.bashrc`, if it defines variables, defines them for any interactive, non-login instance of Bash;
- `.profile`, if it defines variables, defines them for any interactive, login instance of Bash (and other shells).

Thus setting variables in `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` is guaranteed to set them in any corresponding shell instance. Setting variables in `environment.d` files is guaranteed to set them in any corresponding user service instance, which might include shells, but might not (and there might be other intervening layers, see `sshd`).

Another difference I see is that changing `.bashrc` or `.profile` will produce effects in any shell started thereafter; changing `environment.d` will only take effect when the user session and the relevant services are reloaded or restarted.

As [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) mentioned in the comments, `environment.d` files are more limited in their capabilities than the shell initialisation scripts.

Comment: The doco that you hyperlinked there is false anyway.  GNOME Terminal does not operate in the way [that Zbigniew Jędrzejewski-Szmek thinks](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/3ea2b1137b6a929895510d88b89e2091bc34cb21).  The environment to employ for each spawned child [is passed in from the client](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/7409fa84a9c99dd4700130a1419119b3f69426e3/src/terminal-client-utils.c#L121), and the environment of the GNOME Terminal server process itself is ignored.